# Unsatisfied Dependency Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

*Приветсвую всех*  , вопрос такого характера , *Я* , пытаюсь сделать простую сортировку товаров по категориям на *Java Spring* . Вот код :

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/api/all/find" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public @ResponseBody Iterable<Product> Find(@RequestParam String product_title, Map<String , Object> model) {



    if(product_title != null && product_title != " "){
        return productRepo.findAllByTitle(product_title);
    }
    else {
        return productRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

```
public interface ProductRepo  extends CrudRepository<Product , Long> {

        List<Product> findAllByTitle(String product_title);

}
```

Но при попытки запуска компилятор выдает мне вот такую ошибку :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'productController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'productRepo'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'productRepo': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed
>   to create query for method public abstract java.util.List
>   com.example.WebRestApi.repo.ProductRepo.findAllByTitle(java.lang.String)!
>   No property title found for type Product!

И это :

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'productRepo': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed
>   to create query for method public abstract java.util.List
>   com.example.WebRestApi.repo.ProductRepo.findAllByTitle(java.lang.String)!
>   No property title found for type Product!

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в контроллер

```
  @Autowired
  private ProductRepo productRepo;
```

Только сортировки я у вас не увидел, что-то вроде этого:

```
  public interface ProductRepo  extends CrudRepository<Product , Long> {

    List<Product> findAllByTitleOrderByCategory(String product_title);

  }
```

вот здесь он написал что в Product у него нет поля title

> ProductRepo.findAllByTitle(java.lang.String)! No property title found for type Product!

Comment: Выдает всю туже ошибку

Comment: Проверьте сущность Product поле title

Comment: Выложите уже класс Product.